# How to create a stacked bar chart for three sets of data?

Tags: javascript, charts, asp.net-core, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts to visualize some metrics and I've ran into a bit of a snag.  Right now I have a bar graph that looks like this (code below)[image: Current Chart]
and the code behind it is

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar', 'corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Branch Office', 'DataSet 1', 'DataSet 2', 'DataSet 3'],
            ['Chicago', 400, 500, 1000],
            ['New York', 400, 500, 1000],
            ['Seattle', 400, 500, 1000],
            ['Average', 400, 500, 1000]
        ]);

        var options = {
            chart: {
                //title: 'Sales Order Performance',
                //subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
            },
            bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
            hAxis: { format: 'decimal' },
            height: 400,
            colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

        var btns = document.getElementById('btn-group');

        btns.onclick = function (e) {

            if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
                options.hAxis.format = e.target.id === 'none' ? '' : e.target.id;
                chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

html

```
<body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

Taken from some similar answers, the closest I have gotten is modifying a few already posted fiddles but nothing seems to work quite how I need it to.  I am trying to combine the chart that I've provided with a Stacked Bar Graph (as demonstrated and explained [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#labeling-bars) but all the little one-off hacks I've seen around Google or on Stack Overflow do not get me what I need.

I essentially want the "DataSet 3" bar to be able to be broken down into a bar similar to this

[image: Stacked Bar Chart]

How can I turn the chart I already have into a stacked bar graph that has 3 bars per data point?  And if that can't be done, what is the closest that I can do to get a similar result?

Edit: Forgot to add the fiddle I mentioned earlier.  This is as close as I've gotten to the final result that I need http://jsfiddle.net/qv325979/126/ but it's still not quite right and the example that I started working with had to be heavily modified to get to this point.  I essentially am trying to get it to where there are 3 bars (instead of 2) and that the top 2 bars for each item have 1 data point and the bottom bar can be split up into 5 or so.

I do not fully understand how to break the bars up though and why the top bar in that fiddle has 5 separate segments while the red bar only has 1 so if anyone more knowledgeable can explain why that would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the fiddle, setting the `series.5` option, breaks the last column from the stack...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat so what is the way to achieve the desired result where I have 2 bars with only 1 segment and then a 3rd bar with 5 or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to *have 2 bars with only 1 segment and then a 3rd bar with 5 or so*...

use the `series` option on the first two series to isolate each bar

use the `hAxes` option to hide the additional axis' labels

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Branch Office', 'DataSet 1', 'DataSet 2', 'DataSet 3-0', 'DataSet 3-1', 'DataSet 3-2', 'DataSet 3-3', 'DataSet 3-4'],
      ['Chicago', 400, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
      ['New York', 400, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
      ['Seattle', 400, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
      ['Average', 400, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200]
    ]);

    var options = {
      hAxes: {
        1: {
          textStyle: {
            color: 'transparent'
          }
        },
        2: {
          textStyle: {
            color: 'transparent'
          }
        }
      },
      bars: 'horizontal',
      colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3'],
      hAxis: {
        format: 'decimal'
      },
      height: 400,
      isStacked: true,
      series: {
        0: {
          targetAxisIndex: 1
        },
        1: {
          targetAxisIndex: 2
        }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  },
  packages: ['bar']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

using a *core* chart is another option,
the following config option will get the chart *close* to the look & feel of *material*

`theme: 'material'`

however, *core* charts don't group the same as *material*

so have to create the groups manually, within the data,
including rows for spacing

nor will it adjust the last color automatically

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Branch Office', 'DataSet 1', 'DataSet 2', 'DataSet 3-0', 'DataSet 3-1', 'DataSet 3-2', 'DataSet 3-3', 'DataSet 3-4'],
      [' ', 400, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      ['Chicago', null, 500, null, null, null, null, null],
      [' ', null, null, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
      [' ', null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [' ', 400, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      ['New York', null, 500, null, null, null, null, null],
      [' ', null, null, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
      [' ', null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [' ', 400, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      ['Seattle', null, 500, null, null, null, null, null],
      [' ', null, null, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
      [' ', null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      [' ', 400, null, null, null, null, null, null],
      ['Average', null, 500, null, null, null, null, null],
      [' ', null, null, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
    ]);

    var options = {
      colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#4a148c', '#7b1fa2', '#9c27b0', '#ba68c8', '#e1bee7'],
      bar: {
        groupWidth: '90%'
      },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'decimal'
      },
      height: 400,
      isStacked: true,
      theme: 'material'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I've noticed in your example the bars go all the way to the end despite only having values like 400, 500, etc.  In your snippet the DataSet 2 doesn't go all the way, but when I run it locally all 3 bars go all the way to the end.  Is that something wrong with how the table is set up?  Also is there a difference between the way you set up your function versus how I set mine up?  For instance yours seems to be in the actual chart load whereas mine was done after the chart was loaded.

Comment: i typically include the `callback` in the `load` statement -- same as `setOnLoadCallback` -- as for values _going all the way_ -- didn't notice  at first, but that is due to the multiple axis' -- remove the options for `color: 'transparent'` and it will make sense -- there are three lines of x-axis labels -- each probably end with a different value -- using a core chart vs. material would allow for more flexibility dealing with such issues -- because [there are many options that simply don't work on _material_ charts](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)...

Comment: Thanks again for the response.  I originally chose material because it looked like it was the closest chart to what I wanted to build.  I don't really have experience with either - but I will look into core charts instead.  How would a core chart change the example you provided?

Comment: well, I was thinking since more options would be available with _core_, it would be easier to manipulate -- but because of the difference in grouping between the charts, much more manipulation is required for _core_ -- but at least the axis scale is correct. -- BUT check tooltips on _extra_ city rows -- city doesn't show, the space does (`' '`) -- i have code for custom tooltips if needed...

Comment: I don't think that'd be needed.  It looks like this is sort of recreating material charts using core charts and just making them _feel_ like material - is that correct?  If that's the case, will populating the data in the bars be a hassle down the road or will it be easy enough to maintain?

Specifically in terms of sorting, or when there are 50 items (people rather than branch offices, that all need the same 3 bars, for example) will this core chart work or due to the nature of how it's created to appear like a material chart, will I have problems?

Comment: The good news is I always have the same 5 sections for the lowest bar per section so I can hard code colors for that no problem.  My worry is how these will be able to be sorted or manipulated / calculated since it's not really grouped, but just _looks_ like it is.

Comment: i prefer using _core_, since so many options don't work with _material_, regardless, i've found much manipulation is required when using google charts in general, so not uncommon -- plus, don't how you would get the axis scale correct with _material_, as for sorting and other actions, keep a copy of the original -- and write algorithm to feed data to chart afterwards...

Comment: Makes sense.  Maybe I should have also specified the intent of this chart is to have a dropdown at the top of the screen that allows you to filter by branch location, by various employees, etc.  So if you select "Branch Office" in the dropdown, it'd show the chart with branch offices and their respected charts (as shown in my example) and if you selected "Employee" it'd show 50 or so rows each with their own 3 bars as well, and default sorting of best to worst performance.  Does that change how to approach either of your two suggestions?

Comment: great questions! you could solve the filter issue by including the names of the cities, instead of the space (`' '`) -- to hide the extra labels, the chart can be modified after it is drawn on the `'ready'` event, find the label via svg "dom", change color to `'transparent'` -- can help with that too...

Comment: when you say "drop down", are you referring to the [`CategoryFilter` control](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#categoryfilter)? if so, another filter option would be to disconnect the filter from the chart, listen for the `'statechange'` event on the filter, then filter the original data manually, and again, feed the chart...

Comment: I think for the type of data we're using and for the purpose of these charts, this may have been a bit ambitious.  It would have been nice to have but I think I'll just need to do separate charts.  There were things I wasn't considering with sorting the charts that your answer made me consider.  Thanks so much for the work you put in!  Marking as accepted answer.